# react.development.js:1622 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

Tags: react-hooks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fFoH.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVu8t.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppCWW.png)Hello guys I'm having trouble with this error.

I have checked the useState in every component, looked for a solution on google but couldn't find anything.